# Creating Notes user with Powershell 5

Tags: powershell, lotus-notes

Having hunted around a bit I've found that apparently some Lotus Script works in [`powershell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powershell) but I'm trying to create a user and nobody seems to have any posts on that.

I'm starting with

```
$notes = New-Object -ComObject Lotus.NotesSession
$notes.Initialize()
```

But from there I get stuck any tips or ideas would be appreciated, if you know how to specify groups as well that'd be wonderful.

I've developed the script to this point

```
$notes = New-Object -ComObject Lotus.NotesSession
$notes.Initialize()    
Set notesRegistration.RegisterNewUser "Test User"
Set reg.RegistrationServer "NotesServer"
Set reg.CreateMailDb "True"
Set reg.CertifierIDFile "\\IdStore\LOTUS\ids\Servers\cert.id"
Set reg.Expiration "dt"
Set reg.IDType "ID_HIERARCHICAL"
Set reg.MinPasswordLength "0"          
Set reg.OrgUnit "Domain.com"
Set reg.RegistrationLog "log.nsf"
Set reg.UpdateAddressBook "True"
Set reg.StoreIDInAddressBook "True"
Set reg.RegisterNewUser "Test User"
Set Reg.IdLocation "\\Idstore\data\lotus\Ids\tuser.id"
  "CN=NotesServer",  
  "Test",                         
  "",                             
  "Certifierpassword",                   
  ""                              
  "",                              
  "tuser.nsf",                     
  "",                              
  "Domain.com"
```

I'm getting no errors but I'm also getting no success is there anything glaringly obvious that I'm miss?

Comment: I've developed the script to this

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer but some hints.
(I know close to nothing about Powershell so forgive me if I err.)

Powershell does not seem to be the natural weapon of choice to register a new user, since you are touching some of the very core functions of Notes, namely security, PKI and identity.

However, since you can instanciate a NotesSession object, there is hope. Your next stop would be the [`NotesRegistration`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESREGISTRATION_CLASS.html) class.
Note that you will have to handle two sets of credentials : one for a user authorized to register new users (typically an administrator) and one for the certifier.

Another option *could* be to plant a request document in the `admin4.nsf` database then let the admin process do its job.

Now, what to do would depend on how many users you want to register, how often, and whether some manual steps are acceptable. One middle ground would be to utilize the [text file options](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_registeringusersfromatextfile_t.html).

A point to consider would be where you get the user's detail from. When time comes to register a person as a Notes user, chances are that those details are already stored in some database somewhere. Starting with a Notes agent rather than a Powershell script would allow you to leverage Domino's connectivity features to retrieve said details.

Finaly, automating users registration is certainly tempting. I've seen it done well in some places *but* it requires a solid grasp on both Domino administration and Domino development.

Comment: For a little background we have a ps script that we use for new ad accounts and I'm looking to expand the functionality of that so it would be used when we had a new starter and would get its information from the script

Answer (score 0):

Grab a copy of Tivoli Directory Integrator (also now known as IBM Security Integrator). Version 7.x comes with (a limited entitlement with) Domino. There you setup a pipeline that does whatever you need.
My wild guess: Keeping AD users and Notes users on the same page. This problem has [been solved](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFI8Z1Qgz9k). No need to powershell. More samples are [On the TDI UG website](http://www.tdi-users.org/twiki/bin/view/Integrator/WebHome)

Comment: We create our users with a powershell script because we can add in certain fields that we use, so I'm looking to be able to adapt that to create the Notes user at the same time. ideally not using a 3rd party piece of software

Comment: You pick the level of your suffering yourself. The minimum of loose coupling: create a web/rest service and use power shell post to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just started with this and are having the same problem, I've never used Lotus Notes before

What I think is that you're using Lotus script, powershell can't do that

I recently made a script to delete people from Notes, maybe that can give you a hint how powershell utilises the comobject:

```
$DomSession = New-Object -ComObject Lotus.NotesSession
$DomSession.Initialize()
$database = $DomSession.GetDatabase("server/domain","names.nsf")
$domview = $database.GetView('$users')
$deluser = $domview.GetEntryByKey("$upn")| Select-Object -ExpandProperty columnvalues | Select-String -Pattern '^(CN=(?!.*srv22*))' | Select-Object -First 1
$c = $deluser.Line.Split(' ') | Select-Object -First 2
$delete = $c[0]+' '+$c[1]
$adminprocess = $DomSession.CreateAdministrationProcess('server/domain')
$adminprocess.DeleteUser("$delete",$false,0,'')
```

Hope that can be of some help!